# how can i recover to my last folder crushed by the installation of new ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, data-recovery, directory

i install a new operating system Ubuntu in my computer.During the installation i choose to crush the last system.i forget to copy and save all my web project before install the new system

> opt/lampp

please somebody can help me how to find my folder project.thank

Answer (score 0):

If you formatted your HDD, it's not possible to get the system back. Maybe some parts of the project could be recovered using [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) or other recovery software, but I highly doubt that.

Comment: i had just choose the second option(replace ubuntu) when i was install the system

Comment: If you are talking about Ubuntu 16.04, the second option deletes all of your files. I highly doubt that you'll be able to recover them.